# Typing ﬁ ligature

Tags: windows-7, unicode

I'm trying to type "fi" ligature ("ﬁ") on Windows 7. Its unicode code is FB01, or 64257. I tried the two first methods on [this page](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm) (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+fb01 and <kbd>Alt</kbd>064257), but they didn't work.

How to type it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Alt+(F-B-0-1)` generally won't work for reasons we don't need to get into.  In this case, the zero in 064257 isn't needed (although it doesn't hurt).  To get the ligature:

1. Turn on Numlock
2. Hold Alt

   - Type 64257 on the numpad
3. Release Alt

Typing the regular numbers along the top of the keyboard won't work, you have to use the numpad.

Comment: Trying your method gives me different character: "☺".

Comment: I try this in a Notepad in an English-localized Windows 7 with Polish "programmers" keyboard. The font is the default one: Lucida Console--according to Character Map application, it contains this specific ligature. When copy-pasting from Character Map into Notepad the character shows up correctly.